How to delete all rows below after specific symbol and for each id
This is my dataframe:
id         url
25         google.com/main
25         google.com/buy
25         google.com/videos
144        google.com/buy
144        google.com/videos
144        google.com/pictures
992        google.com/main
992        google.com/buy
992        google.com/videos

I would like to delete all rows after url "google.com/buy" for each id. I want this:
id         url
25         google.com/main
25         google.com/buy
144        google.com/buy
992        google.com/main
992        google.com/buy

I think to use "for" or "def", but i can not undestand how

What happens if you have several "google.com/buy" in the same id?

And what happens if you have no match?

You could use groupby.transform with a reverse cummax and boolean indexing:
out = df[df.groupby('id')['url']
           .transform(lambda x: x[::-1].eq('google.com/buy').cummax())]

Output:
    id              url
0   25  google.com/main
1   25   google.com/buy
3  144   google.com/buy
6  992  google.com/main
7  992   google.com/buy

Intermediates:
    id                  url  .eq('google.com/buy')  reverse cummax
0   25      google.com/main                  False            True
1   25       google.com/buy                   True            True
2   25    google.com/videos                  False           False
3  144       google.com/buy                   True            True
4  144    google.com/videos                  False           False
5  144  google.com/pictures                  False           False
6  992      google.com/main                  False            True
7  992       google.com/buy                   True            True
8  992    google.com/videos                  False           False

Note that if you have several "google.com/buy" in the same id, you'll get all the rows up to the last match. If you want to delete after the first match you could use a forward cummax and shift:
out = df[df.groupby('id')['url']
           .transform(lambda x: ~x.eq('google.com/buy')
                                  .cummax().shift(fill_value=False))]

Intermediates (with a more complex input example):
     id                  url  .eq('google.com/buy')  cummax  shift      ~
0    25      google.com/main                  False   False  False   True
1    25       google.com/buy                   True    True  False   True
2    25    google.com/videos                  False    True   True  False
3   144       google.com/buy                   True    True  False   True
4   144    google.com/videos                  False    True   True  False
5   144  google.com/pictures                  False    True   True  False
6   992      google.com/main                  False   False  False   True
7   992       google.com/buy                   True    True  False   True
8   992    google.com/videos                  False    True   True  False
9   992       google.com/buy                   True    True   True  False
10  992  google.com/pictures                  False    True   True  False


mozway, thank you, it works!
